# Flutter fl_chart barchart get and display dynamic data from API

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

Im new in Flutter. Currently Im following a tutorial to implement fl_chart bar chart on my project. The chart is successfully displayed as it is static data. Next, I want to make an API request and display the response data using the same chart. But I just cannot figure out how to implement it.

I want to make an API request and display the response data using the same chart. But I just cannot figure out how to implement it. Here is the code displaying static data.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var name;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadUserData();
    super.initState();
  }

  _loadUserData() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var user = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('user') ?? '[]');

    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        name = user;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Monthly Spending',
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60, left: 20, right: 20),
              child: SizedBox(
                // width: 200,
                height: 300,
                child: BarChart(BarChartData(
                  borderData: FlBorderData(
                    border: const Border(
                      top: BorderSide.none,
                      right: BorderSide.none,
                      left: BorderSide.none,
                      bottom: BorderSide(width: 1)
                    ),
                  ),
                  gridData: FlGridData(show: false),
                  titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                    show: true,
                    bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                      sideTitles: SideTitles(
                        showTitles: true,
                        reservedSize: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                    leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                      sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
                    ),
                    topTitles: AxisTitles(
                      sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
                    ),
                    rightTitles: AxisTitles(
                      sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
                    ),
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  barTouchData: BarTouchData(
                    enabled: false,
                    touchTooltipData: BarTouchTooltipData(
                      tooltipBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                    )
                  ),
                  groupsSpace: 10,
                  barGroups: BarData.barData.map((data) => 
                    BarChartGroupData(x: data.id, barRods: [
                      BarChartRodData(toY: data.y, width:8, color: Colors.purple.shade400)
                      ], showingTooltipIndicators: [0]
                    )
                  ).toList(),
                  // barGroups: BarData.barData(),
                ),
                swapAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                swapAnimationCurve: Curves.linear,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
class BarData {
  static List<Data> barData = [
    Data(
      id: 1,
      y: 2
    ),
    Data(
      id: 3,
      y: 4
    ),
  ];
}
class Data {
  // for ordering in the graph
  int id;
  double y;

  Data({
    required this.id,
    required this.y,
  });
  @override toString() => 'Data: $id, $y';
}
```